# register_nav_menus and wp_nav_menu issue, not displaying independent menus

Tags: menus

My problem is that wordpress isn't showing the two menu's as separate menus, it just outputs on menu to both positions.

URL:
http://www.msc-media.co.uk

Check the header and footer for the links  - I know the footer is ugly, need to sort out the css later.

I've created two menus in the functions.php with this code.

```
<?php
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'topmenu' => 'Top Menu',
        'footermenu' => 'Footer Menu',
    ) );

?>
```

I've then called these menu's in my footer.php and header.php with this code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'footermenu')); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'topmenu')); ?>
```

This is my back-end config with wordpress, getting the top menu to show 4 links, and the footer to display two. With the positions correctly appointed.

[image]

Can anyone explain what is wrong with this? - I'm stumped and I've searched the WP codex/forums for hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footermenu')); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'topmenu')); ?>
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Worked perfectly, what are the differences between 'theme_location' and 'menu'?

Comment: @MChandler Menu accepts the slug of the menu you've created. Theme location accpets a registered theme location. The user can then create a menu, and assign to one (or more) locations, where it will then appear. In theme development, you should *never* use the 'menu' attribute.